# When to use "concrètement" and when to use "plus précisément"

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

In conversation with my friend, I said the following:

> Les lunettes anti lumière bleue ? Pas besoin de t'embêter à t'en procurer. Mon nez et mes oreilles ne supporteraient pas de les porter toute la journée, en tout cas.
>
> Il te suffit en fait d'un petit changement sur ton ordinateur pour réduire la quantité de lumière bleue. **Concrètement** / **Plus précisément**, ça permet d’afficher des couleurs plus chaudes, qui risquent d’ailleurs de t'irriter les yeux pendant quelques jours.
>
> Mais aussi désagréable que ça puisse paraître au début, on va finir par se faire à quoi que ce soit, hein ?

The use of "concrètement" came to mind on the spot, but now I wonder which is actually better suited for the given context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I explain in french, but I can answer/translate in english if you ask me.]

Concret s'oppose à abstrait, général, tandis que précis s'oppose à imprécis, flou.
Un énoncé peut être précis et abstrait (par exemple n'importe quel énoncé mathématique un peu avancé) ou flou et concret ("Il était ici... ah non, là ! à moins qu'il ne fût là-bas..."), ainsi que précis et concret ou flou et abstrait.

On dira donc "Plus précisément" pour passer d'un énoncé flou à un énoncé précis, mais "concrètement" pour passer d'un énoncé abstrait à un énoncé concret :

> — Ils étaient au moins 4.
>
> — Et plus précisément ?
>
> — Je dirais la racine carrée de la somme des carrés de 3 et 4.
>
> — Et concrètement ?
>
> — Je pense qu'ils étaient 5.

A l'oral, cependant, il arrive souvent que l'on confonde les deux notions d'abstraction et d'imprécision.

Voilà pour la théorie. Quant à votre exemple, aucune des deux solutions ne me convient.
Selon moi, votre adverbe n'introduit pas une précision ni un énoncé plus concret, mais plutôt une explication par la finalité. Vous auriez aussi bien pu dire :

> Il te suffit d'un petit changement sur ton ordinateur pour réduire la quantité de lumière bleue, **afin d'afficher/ pour afficher** des couleurs plus chaudes ...

ou plus simplement :

> Il te suffit d'un petit changement sur ton ordinateur pour réduire la quantité de lumière bleue, **et** afficher des couleurs plus chaudes ...

Comment: Juste un point de math, 5 est la racine carrée de la somme des carrés de 3 et 4.

Comment: Merci, c'est corrigé